# Every $g \in \operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ can be written as $g=g_1 s g_2$, where $g_i$ upper triangular and $s$ monomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Every $g \in \operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ can be written as $g=g_1 s g_2$, where $g_1, g_2$ are upper triangular and $s$ is [monomial](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Monomial_matrix) (generalized permutation matrix where the entries can be $\neq 1$).

This would mean that there is a decomposition $NWAN=\operatorname{SL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ with

- $N$ the group of upper triangular matrices with diagonal elements $1$,
- $W$ the group of permutation matrices permutation matrices
- $A$ the diagonal matrices with determinant $1$.

I found this statement in [Metric spaces of non-positive curvature](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-12494-9) by Bridson-Haefliger in the proof of Prop. 10.77 on page 339.

Is this decomposition well known? Bridson-Haefliger proceed to give a proof in Lemma 10.80 for $n=3$ only. I think this proof becomes more complicated for larger $n$. There they use the proof of the Jordan-Hoelder theorem for vectorspaces. Is there a different proof?

---

Edit: The Borel subgroup is $B=AN=NA$, i.e. the diagonal entries can be different from $1$. Then the statement $BWB=\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ holds. Otherwise it might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the decomposition you want, after moving $A$ to the diagonal of $N$:

[Bruhat Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_decomposition)